# Optimize code for output table generation in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I merge this 4 code fragments to **one pipe**?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

v1<- df1 %>%
  select(starts_with("DR0")) %>% names %>%
  paste0("coef-",.)

All<-left_join(All, df1, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("DR0"), ~ coef - .)) %>%
  select(-Week, -DR1) %>%
  rename_at(-c(1:4), ~v1)%>%
  relocate(date1)

All<-All %>% 
  mutate(across(date1:date2, as.Date)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('coef-'), values_to = 'Result') %>% 
  filter(date2 - date1 == as.numeric(str_sub(name, -2))) %>% 
  select(-date1,-name)

All<-data.frame(All)
```

**My data:**

```
 df1 <- structure(list(date1 = c("2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28"), 
                          date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01"), 
                          Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
                          Week = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Friday"), 
                          DR1 = c(4, 1, 6, 3), DR01 = c(4, 1, 4, 3), DR02 = c(4, 2, 6, 2), 
                          DR03 = c(9, 5, 4, 7), DR04 = c(5, 4, 3, 2), DR05 = c(5, 4, 5, 4), 
                          DR06 = c(2, 4, 3, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
    
    All <- structure(list(date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01"), 
                          Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), coef = c(4L, 1L, 6L, 3L)), 
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

**Expected output:**

```
    > All
           date2 Category coef Result
    1 2021-06-30      FDE    4      0
    2 2021-06-30      ABC    1     -1
    3 2021-07-01      FDE    6      2
    4 2021-07-01      ABC    3     -4
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is it possible to put your code as an answer?

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for the answer, if the question is reopened I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do it this way:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(lubridate)  

All_new <- left_join(All, df1, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%    
  mutate(across(starts_with("DR0"), ~ coef - .), across(contains("date"), ymd)) %>%    
  select(-Week, -DR1) %>%   
  rename_with(~ paste0("coef-", .), starts_with("DR0")) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('coef-'), values_to = 'Result') %>%   
  filter(date2 - date1 == as.numeric(str_sub(name, -2))) %>%    
  select(-date1,-name) %>%    
  data.frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es de TarJae:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

All_new <-
  left_join(All, df1, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("DR0"), ~ coef - .), across(contains("date"), ymd)) %>%
  select(-Week,-DR1) %>%
  rename_with( ~ paste0("coef-", .), starts_with("DR0")) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('coef-'), values_to = 'Result') %>%
  filter(date2 - date1 == as.numeric(str_sub(name,-2))) %>%
  select(-date1, -name) %>%
  data.frame()
```